# Use 2 Table View in the same View Controller (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a problem handling 2 tables on the same screen. Every time he keeps crashing. Can someone help me?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: TableViewCellComunicazioni?

    if tableView == self.tableViewNotifica {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNotifica", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellComunicazioni
        let dataNotifica = structNotifica[indexPath.row].dateNotifica
        let testoNotifica = structNotifica[indexPath.row].textNotifica

        cell?.dateNotification.text = "\(date!)"
        cell?.textNotification.text = "\(text!)"
        return cell!
    }
    if tableView == self.tableViewInbox {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellInbox", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellComunicazioni
        let email = structInbox[indexPath.row].email
        let messaggio = structInbox[indexPath.row].messaggio
        let data = structInbox[indexPath.row].data

        cell?.emailInbox.text = "\(email!)"
        cell?.messaggioInbox.text = "\(message!)"
        cell?.dataInbox.text = "\(date!)"
        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: can you show crash log?

Comment: Seems you should have to change data type of cell. As you are using "TableViewCellComunicazioni" in both the cases with different identifies "cellNotifica" and "cellInbox".

Comment: Also instead of forced unwrapping. Use optional binding to unwrap optionals.
date! should be if let date = date {use date here}. Similarly for email, message etc..

Comment: Do you have the same table view cell subclass for two cells with different identifiers? This can be problem. You have two cells of different class but you're trying to downcast them to the same class. But, if downcasting doesn't work `cell` variable isn't assigned and your code crashes on line where you unwrap you cell `return cell!`

Comment: Using same data source for multiple table views complicate things. Try to avoid that.

Comment: Ok, I solved. But I have another question: I have to create a detail screen, so let's say that this detail screen should only be connected to the second table view, how can I say that if I click on the x row of the second table it will show me the View of detail? Because now, this action is only done by clicking in the first table, I need it only if I click on the second. If I click on the first table then I visualize the populated view, if I click on the second one, I visualize the empty view.

Answer (score 1):

*This could be a probable fix for your problem:*

**Coding Example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.tableViewNotifica {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNotifica", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellComunicazioni
        let dataNotifica = structNotifica[indexPath.row].dateNotifica
        let testoNotifica = structNotifica[indexPath.row].textNotifica

        cell?.dateNotification.text = "\(date!)"
        cell?.textNotification.text = "\(text!)"
        return cell!
    }
    if tableView == self.tableViewInbox {
        let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellInbox", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellComunicazioni
        let email = structInbox[indexPath.row].email
        let messaggio = structInbox[indexPath.row].messaggio
        let data = structInbox[indexPath.row].data

        cell?.emailInbox.text = "\(email!)"
        cell?.messaggioInbox.text = "\(message!)"
        cell?.dataInbox.text = "\(date!)"
        return cell!
    }
      return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

**And make sure that you have correct cell identifier for dequeuing.**

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listmoviesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == moviesTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setupCell(listmoviesArray[indexPath.row],indexPath: indexPath)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setupCell(listmoviesArray[indexPath.row],indexPath: indexPath)
            return cell
        }

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == moviesTableView {
    // Handle your selection for row. 
    } else {
       //Handle your selection for row.
    }
  }
}
```

**Above code produces the following output with 2 Tableview.**

[image]

Comment: Ok, I solved. But I have another question: I have to create a detail screen, so let's say that this detail screen should only be connected to the second table view, how can I say that if I click on the x row of the second table it will show me the View of detail? Because now, this action is only done by clicking in the first table, I need it only if I click on the second. If I click on the first table then I visualize the populated view, if I click on the second one, I visualize the empty view.

Comment: @DomenicoCascone In your did Select row method of table view delegate you can add check for tableview

Comment: Updating my answer for your this query